# Magento Database Repair Tool Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, magento

I'm trying to upgrade my magento 1.3.2.4 database to 1.4.0.1 by using "Magento database repair tool", but it's not working. When I enter the details launch the script it takes ages and still nothing happens (once I waited about and hour) and I have a decent server (dual Xeons, 16 GB RAM, 2xSAS RAID).

When I get fed up waiting and refresh the page, or launch the script from the beginning, it gives me this error message:

Error #1005: Can't create table 'temp.#sql-b4a_26b' (errno: 150) on SQL:

```
ALTER TABLE `magento_wishlist_item` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `FK_WISHLIST_ITEM_STORE` 
FOREIGN KEY (`store_id`) 
REFERENCES `magento_core_store` (`store_id`) 
ON DELETE SET NULL 
ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing it slightly wrong as repair tool is not meant for upgrading but repairing existing state

for a successful upgrade do as follows:

- disable all community and local extensions
- disable all core rewrites
- revert to default theme
- perform upgrade
- enable extensions one by one and enjoy debugging

Comment: This is not gonna work, I'm trying all kinds of ways and dozens of tutorials, nothing works so far.

Comment: try and you will be amazed also don't upgrade to 1.4.0.1 right away but upgrade version by version till the version you actually need to upgrade